# MySQL: Select penult values

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-order-by

There are 2 tables:

table1:

```
id  |phone| order|
 ---|-----|------|
  1 | 122 |  6   |
  2 | 122 |  4   |
  3 | 122 |  3   |
  4 | 123 |  6   |
  5 | 123 |  5   |
  6 | 123 |  3   |   
  7 | 124 |  6   |
  8 | 124 |  5   |
  9 | 125 |  6   |
  10| 125 |  5   |
```

table2:

```
|phone |
|------|
|122   |
|123   |
|124   |
```

I have to select id and last order according next conditions:

- If order not equals 3 take row with max id value for this phone
- If order equals 3  take pre-max id  for this phone
- Id is in table2.

So result should be:

```
|phone  | order|
|------ |------|
|122    | 4    |
|123    | 5    |
|124    | 5    |
```

MySQL version: Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB

Comment: How do establish 'last' - is there an auto_increment  column, date or something else which would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to look at the last two records; if the last record has order `3`, then use the previous one.

That would have been a simple query with window functions and/or lateral joins be your old MySQL version does not support these features. User variables are an option, as demonstrated by nbk, but they are tricky to use - and MySQL 8.0 annonced that this feature will be deprecated in a future version.

I am going to recommend correlated subqueries and a little logic:

```
select t2.id,
    coalesce(
        nullif((select ord from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id order by odering_id desc limit 1), 3),
        (select ord from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id order by odering_id desc limit 1, 1)
    ) as ord
from table2 t2
```

The first subquery gets the latest value; `nullif()` checks the returned value and returns `null` if it has order `3`; this indicate `coalesce()` that it should return the result of the second subquery, that gets the previous value.

`order` is a language keyword, so I used `ord` instead.

**[Demo in MySQL 5.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8cef9104b27590d4bfc436033f8acc05)**:

```
 id | ord
--: | --:
122 |   4
123 |   5
124 |   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mariadb version is a little old

Thta will use the row number sorted by the `order` column and it will select onl ythe second one.

the LIMIT in the subquery is needed,, because mariadb follows the standard and would not sort the subselect.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`id` int, `order` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`id`, `order`)
> VALUES
>     (122, 6),
>     (122, 4),
>     (122, 3),
>     (123, 6),
>     (123, 5),
>     (123, 3),
>     (124, 6),
>     (124, 5),
>     (125, 6),
>     (125, 5)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table2
>     (`id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table2
>     (`id`)
> VALUES
>     (122),
>     (123),
>     (124)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id,`order`
> FROM (SELECT 
>
>  t1.`order`
> , IF ( @id = t1.id ,@rn := @rn +1, @rn:= 1) AS rownum
> , @id := t1.`id` as id
> FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id,(SELECT @id := 0,@rn := 0) t3
> ORDEr BY t1.id,t1.`order` DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) t4
> WHERE rownum = 2
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | order
> --: | ----:
> 122 |     4
> 123 |     5
> 124 |     5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9bbd3d898ab1a7abfb6fc1ab290e158f)*